# Set text colour on specific list text

Tags: vbscript, hta

I've setup a VBScript hta to let my users choose a default printer.
I'm currently trying to make it as clear as possible visually.

If possible I'd like to hide the print server address from the front of each network printer listed.

E.g. the diaglogue box currently shows '\\SERVPRT2\Printer_Name' for each printer, but I'd like it to show just 'Printer_Name'. Or if that's not possible then to maybe just format the surplus text with a more subtle colour.

I've listed my code below - does any one know if this is possible? Many thanks

```
    <html> 
<head>
    <title>Choose your default printer</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
    body { 
        font-family:Verdana; 
        font-size: 12px; 
        color: #49403B; 
        background: #FFFFFF; 
        text-align: center; 
        } 
</style> 

<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">

    Sub Window_Onload
window.resizeTo 500,550
        strComputer = "."

        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
        Set colPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Printer")

        For Each objPrinter in colPrinters
            strPrinter = objPrinter.Name
            Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
            objOption.Text = strprinter
            objOption.Value = strPrinter
            AvailablePrinters.Add(objOption)
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub SetDefault
        strPrinter = AvailablePrinters.Value
        Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
        WshNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter strPrinter
        Msgbox strprinter & " has been set as your default printer."
    End Sub

</SCRIPT>

Select your default printer, then click the button below<p>

<select size="20" name="AvailablePrinters"></select><p>
<input type="button" value="Set as Default" onClick="SetDefault">
<p>
Close this window after setting a printer as default<p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you just need to remove the printserver from the displayed name (the `Text` attribute). A regular expression replacement is probably the best way to achieve that:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^\\\\.*?\\"

For Each objPrinter in colPrinters
    strPrinter = objPrinter.Name
    Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
    objOption.Text = re.Replace(strprinter, "")
    objOption.Value = strPrinter
    AvailablePrinters.Add(objOption)
Next
```

Note that this may cause confusion for the user when there are printer queues with the same name on different print servers.

---

On a separate note, I'd like to recommend some usability improvements for your code:

- Pre-select the default printer, so the user sees which one is currently the default:

  ```
  For Each objPrinter in colPrinters
      strPrinter = objPrinter.Name
      Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
      objOption.Text = re.Replace(strprinter, "")
      objOption.Value = strPrinter
      If objPrinter.Default Then objOption.Selected = True
      AvailablePrinters.Add(objOption)
  Next
  ```
- Automatically change the default printer when the selection changes and remove the <kbd>Set as Default</kbd> button. That reduces the number of clicks for the user.

  ```
  <select size="20" name="AvailablePrinters" onChange="SetDefault"></select>
  ```

Comment: Ansgar you are amazing! That does the job perfectly and your additions are fantastic, just what I needed. Really happy with the less clicks needed! Just one more question - do you know if it's possible to also sort the printers by name so that they're in name order? Many thanks, Jez